# Can we change the size of Native Heap memory (16 MB) in Android

Tags: android

Maximum native memory that can be allocated to an android app is 16 MB for all apps but i want to change this heap size through code is it possible ?

Answer (score 5):

No. Not without extreme trouble (think rooting, new roms, stuff like that).

(Also, it's not 16 for all devices, some have more)

Comment: Thanks for replying Nanne.
Yep i am in extreme trouble and need to increase my native memory size and yet did not get anything to work over it :(

I wish i could get a way to increase it size.

Comment: you won't probably, its because you have devices with low memory, and you need to 'share' with others, so its an android restriction you need to cope with.